# Linked list in C with OMP : memory issues

Tags: c, multithreading, linked-list, thread-safety

I've adapted a very nice omp-parallelized code to perform numerical integration I found [here](https://doc.itc.rwth-aachen.de/display/CCP/Parallelizing+an+Algorithm+for+Adaptive+Integration+with+OpenMP).
However, some massif profiling revealed that there is some serious memory-leaking going on...
I guess this is related to how popping elements from the stack is handeled, where the top element on the stack is returned but not removed from the stack.

So I figured, I could easily add this missing feature as I've done this before in serial code.
But I'm obiously doing something wrong because I'm getting an "invalid pointer error" after a couple of "frees" ...

Since I'm completely new to OMP I figured, I could ask you guys for help.
I'm really sorry, that I wasn't able to cut done my "example" more.
But I think, that it's important to see how the author implemented the linked list and which datastructures.

I guess most of the code below may be skipped, it looks fine to me.
The problem arises when I try to "free" the data associated with the top element of the stack in the function "pop_stack" at the very end.

Popping elements in serial seems to work fine - inside the parallel section it doesn't.
Can you spot the mistake(s) ?

Note: This is incomplete code. It won't compile.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <math.h>



int num_threads;
#define INITIAL_STACK_SIZE 128   



/* the stack structure */
struct stack_s{               
  int el_count;            /* count of elements on stack */    
  int el_size;             /* size of an element */
  int mem_reserve;         /* allocated memory for stack */
  void* elements;          /* pointer to begin of stack */
};


struct myparams { double c1; double c1;};


typedef struct _work_t{
  double a;
  double b;
  double rec; /* max recursion depth */
  struct myparams * p; 
} work_t;
typedef struct stack_s* stack_t;


void create_stack(stack_t* stack, int element_size);
int empty_stack(stack_t stack);
void push_stack(stack_t stack, void* element);
void pop_stack(stack_t stack, void* element);

double do_something( 
  double (*f)(double,struct myparams*), /* function to be called  */
  double a,
  double b,
  int rec,   /*max. recursion depth*/
  struct myparams* p);



static double myfun(double x,struct myparams* p){ return  exp(-x*x)/p->a+log(x*pow(p->b,2.0));}

int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
  num_threads=omp_get_num_threads();
  double a=somevalue;
  double b=somevalue;

  struct myparams pinit;
  pinit.c1=someval;
  pinit.c2=someval;
  double answer=0;

  #pragma omp parallel
  {
    answer = do_something(myfun, xmin, xmax, 100, &pinit);
  } /* omp parallel */


  return 0;
}


double do_something( 
  double (*f)(double,struct myparams*), /* function to be called  */
  double a,
  double b,
  int rec,
  struct myparams* p)
{
  stack_t stack;
  work_t work;

  int ready, idle, busy;

  /* prepare stack */
  work.a = a;
  work.b = b;
  work.rec=rec;  
  work.p=p;


  create_stack(&stack, sizeof(work_t));
  push_stack(stack, &work);

  double result = 0.0;

  busy = 0;

#pragma omp parallel default(none) \
    shared(stack, result,f,busy) \
    private(work, idle, ready)
  {

    ready = 0;
    idle = 1;

    while(!ready )
    {

#pragma omp critical (stack)
      {
        if (!empty_stack(stack)){
          /* we have new work */ 
          pop_stack(stack, &work);

          if (idle){
            /* say others i'm busy */
            busy += 1;
            idle = 0;
          }

        }else{
          /* no new work on stack */
          if (!idle){
            busy -= 1;
            idle = 1;
          }

          /* nobody has anything to do; let us leave the loop */
          if (busy == 0)
            ready = 1;

        }
      } /* end critical(stack) */

      if (idle)
        continue;

      /* do some calculations using values saved in work and as well as the function f 
         along with the function parameters saved in myparams
         -> estimate an error  & save it to 'delta' */

      if(rec <= 0 || fabs(delta) <= global_tolerance) 
      {  
        //error acceptable
#pragma omp critical (result) 
        result += somevalue_computed_above;
      }
      else // error not acceptable
      {    
        //push 2 new work-elements to stack 
        //prepare 1st new elem.
        work.a = some_new_a;
        work.b = some_new_b;
        work.rec=rec-1;

  #pragma omp critical (stack)
        {
          push_stack(stack, &work);      
          //prepare 2nd new element
          work.a = some_new_a2;
          work.b = some_new_b2;
          work.rec=rec-1;
          push_stack(stack, &work);

        }      
      }
    } /* while */
  } /* end omp parallel */


  return result;
}

/******************************************
 * create new stack
 ******************************************/
void 
create_stack(
             stack_t* stack,     /* stack to create */
             int element_size)   /* size of a stack element */
{
  int initial_size = INITIAL_STACK_SIZE;

  /* allocate memory for new stack struct */
  (*stack) = (stack_t) malloc(sizeof(struct stack_s));
  if (!(*stack)){
    fprintf(stderr, "error: could not allocate memory for stack.. Abort.\n"); 
    exit(1);
  }    

  /* allocate memory for stack elements */
  (*stack)->elements = (void*) malloc(element_size * initial_size);
  (*stack)->mem_reserve = initial_size; 
  if (!(*stack)->elements){
    fprintf(stderr, "error: could not allocate memory for stack.. Abort.\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  (*stack)->el_size = element_size;
  (*stack)->el_count = 0;

}

/*****************************************
 * check if the stack is empty 
 *****************************************/
int 
empty_stack
(stack_t stack)
{
  return stack->el_count <= 0;
}


/*****************************************
 * push a element on stack
 *****************************************/
void 
push_stack(
           stack_t stack,    /* target stack */
           void* element)    /* element to push */
{
  int i, new_reserve;
  int log2_count;

  /* check if we need more memory for stack */    
  if (stack->el_count >= stack->mem_reserve){

      /* calculate new size for the stack
         it should be a power of two */
      for (i = stack->el_count, log2_count = 0; 
           i > 0; 
           i>>1, log2_count++);
      new_reserve = 1 << log2_count;

      /* reallocate memory for phase thread tables 
         and nullify new values */
      stack->elements = (void *) realloc(stack->elements, 
                      stack->el_size * new_reserve);
      if (!stack->elements){
        fprintf(stderr, "error: can't reallocate stack.. Aborting\n");
        exit(1);
      }

      stack->mem_reserve = new_reserve;
  }

  /* now push the element on top of the stack */
  memcpy((char*)stack->elements + stack->el_count*stack->el_size, 
            element, stack->el_size);
  stack->el_count++;

}

/*****************************************
 * pop an element from stack 
 * THIS IS WHERE I SUSPECT A MISTAKE !
 *****************************************/
void pop_stack(
          stack_t stack,    /* target stack */
          void* element)    /* where poped el. should be stored */
{
  if (stack->el_count <= 0){
    fprintf(stderr, "error: trying to pop from empty stack.\n");
    exit(2);
  }

  stack->el_count--;
  memcpy(element, 
         (char*)stack->elements + stack->el_count*stack->el_size, 
         stack->el_size);

  // try to remove last element from stack
  // in original code there was no cleanup
  struct _work_t *tmp = (struct _work_t*) stack->elements+stack->el_count; 
  printf("ncount:%d, foo:%f\n",stack->el_count+1,tmp->a);
  free(tmp); //Works as long as el_count == 1 but fails if it becomes 2

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like `pop_stack()` is only called inside some `stack` related critical region, so we can stop worrying about data races.

You identify this part of the code:

```
/*****************************************
 * pop an element from stack 
 * THIS IS WHERE I SUSPECT A MISTAKE !
 *****************************************/
void pop_stack(
          stack_t stack,    /* target stack */
          void* element)    /* where poped el. should be stored */
{
  if (stack->el_count <= 0){
    fprintf(stderr, "error: trying to pop from empty stack.\n");
    exit(2);
  }

  stack->el_count--;
  memcpy(element, 
         (char*)stack->elements + stack->el_count*stack->el_size, 
         stack->el_size);

  // try to remove last element from stack
  // in original code there was no cleanup
  struct _work_t *tmp = (struct _work_t*) stack->elements+stack->el_count; 
  printf("ncount:%d, foo:%f\n",stack->el_count+1,tmp->a);
  free(tmp); //Works as long as el_count == 1 but fails if it becomes 2
}
```

as the possible seat of the problem.  So the `push_stack()` clearly copies `stack->el_size` bytes of the `element` to the stack, and `pop_stack()` copies them back again.  That all looks wonderful.  The last part of `pop_stack()` is, however, a bit of a puzzle...

```
  struct _work_t *tmp = (struct _work_t*) stack->elements+stack->el_count;
  printf("ncount:%d, foo:%f\n",stack->el_count+1,tmp->a);
  free(tmp); //Works as long as el_count == 1 but fails if it becomes 2
```

`stack->elements` is a `void*` pointer to the first byte of the first element, so adding `stack->el_count` to that does **not** give you the address of the element that has just been popped, except when `stack->el_count == 0` !!  So `tmp` is set to a nonsense value, and `tmp->a` is also, therefore, nonsense.  As for the `free(tmp)`... only when `el_count == 0` (now) will the `free()` *not* fail, but it will destroy the `stack`.

Looking at the way the `stack` works does not suggest to me that the `pop_stack()` needs to do any "cleanup".  If you think it does, then you need to reconsider what that really needs to be.  It's possible that you are using the `stack` as a stack of pointers to "stuff"... but in any case, there's a little more work to be done.

Comment: thank you for your clarification. I really appreciate your effort.

Comment: ...yet I'm a little bit worried about "  create_stack(&stack, sizeof(work_t));
  push_stack(stack, &work);" in the function do_something(...) .. The function itself  is within a #pragma omp parallel region . Doen't this lead to a redundant allocation of "stack" if every thread does this?

Comment: I know next to nothing about OMP.  But, yes, every time `do_something()` is called, it sets up its own `stack`, and then appears to spawn threads to work on that `stack`.  In `main()` it looks like more than one thread may run `do_something()`, but if so, I would assume them to be quite separate.

Comment: @ODIUM: it is, however, true that `do_something()` returns without freeing the body of its `stack`.  So it would be tidy to have a `destroy_stack()` and call it just before the return in `do_something()`.